# How to write isNumber() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My guess would be:

```
function isNumber(val) {
    return val === +val;
}
```

Is there a better way?

**Previous Reference**

[Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/174921#174921)

Comment: What is your expectation for the following values: `NaN`, `Infinity`, `'1'`, `1`?

Comment: You can use the implementation from jQuery for this: [jQuery.isNumeric](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.isNumeric)

Comment: The real numbers from math.

Comment: I just have to ask, couldn't you find an answer in the exact duplicate question you yourself posted in the question ?

Comment: It looks to be the superior answer.

Comment: The accepted answer is properly tested, and it's the same solution I always tend to use without any issues, so what's the problem with that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "this would not handle negative numbers"? `-1` is equal to `+-1`.

Comment: `return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);`

Answer (score 41):

```
var isNumber = function isNumber(value) 
{
   return typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value);
}
```

This code above is taken from the book "JavaScript - the good parts".

/* ANSWER UPDATE BEGIN - in reply to some comments 
below from the person who asked the question and others */

```js
var isNumber = function isNumber(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value);
}

var isNumberObject = function isNumberObject(n) {
  return (Object.prototype.toString.apply(n) === '[object Number]');
}

var isCustomNumber = function isCustomNumber(n){
  return isNumber(n) || isNumberObject(n);
}

console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(5)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(5.2)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(5.5)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(-1)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(-1.5)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(-0.0)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(0.0)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(0)));
console.log(isCustomNumber(new Number(1e5)));

console.log(isCustomNumber(5));
console.log(isCustomNumber(5.2));
console.log(isCustomNumber(5.5));
console.log(isCustomNumber(-1));
console.log(isCustomNumber(-1.5));
console.log(isCustomNumber(-0.0));
console.log(isCustomNumber(0.0));
console.log(isCustomNumber(0));
console.log(isCustomNumber(1e5));
```

/* ANSWER UPDATE END - in reply to some comments 
below from the person who asked the question and others */

Comment: I like typeof but what is the isFinite for?

Comment: "The isFinite function is the best way of determining whether a value can be used as a number because it rejects NaN and Infinity." This is also a quote from the same book.

Comment: I see, JavaScript considers these values number because they are of type number but used to describe Not a Number.

Comment: Why you use named function expression?

Comment: @Givi: most likely so that similar to native functions, the name is shown in the `toString` representation of it.

Comment: I don't particularly like this one because `isNumber(new Number(5))` would return `false`.

Comment: what in the holy heck does new Number(5) do? `var test = 5 vs var test = new Number(5)`

Comment: how does that created something that is not a number??

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting, `new Number(5)` creates a `Number` object, rather than a value. It's pretty much never used, so it's not really an issue, but I prefer to allow for objects to be treated as numbers, such as `Date`, `Boolean`, and any custom objects that have `valueOf` overridden.

Comment: if the language allow it, it must have some purpose?

Comment: This check I quoted in my answer is as strict as possible. It is a book quote. The object new Number(5) is not a number in JS, that's obvious. So if you want to customize this check for special purposes - feel free. And my best guess of implementing that custom definition is there - see the update to my answer (this extension I think follows the philosophy of the book, and I like the book a lot, as the author really really knows what he's talking about).

Comment: Just use `Number.isFinite` instead. It returns a `false` for non-`number` values.

Answer (score 15):

If you do not want to include strings, and you do want to include Infinity, 
you can compare the Number coercion of the argument to the argument:

```
function isNumber(n){
    return Number(n)=== n;
}
```

//test

```
[0, 1, 2, -1, 1.345e+17, Infinity, false, true, NaN, '1', '0'].map(function(itm){
    return itm+'= '+isNumber(itm);
});

// returned values
0= true
1= true
2= true
-1= true
134500000000000000= true
Infinity= true
false= false
true= false
NaN= false
'1'= false
'0'= false
```

Comment: Do you consider `01` Numeric? If so this fails that case

Comment: `Number(01) === 01 === true` test this in a console -- it's truthy.

Answer (score 11):

```
function isNumber(val){
    return typeof val==='number';
}
```

Comment: and of course `&& !isNaN(val)` because `typeof NaN` is number.

Comment: @FarzadYousefzadeh TIL that 'Not a Number' is of type 'number'. Gotta love javascript.

Answer (score 6):

If you want `"23"` to be a number, then

```
function isNumber(val) {
    return !isNaN(val);
}
```

Comment: above function will given wrong with null and empty string , use follwing for right one
function isNumber(n) {
   return  !n && isFinite(n)
}

Comment: it return true when val is empty string. but nice and simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function isNumber(val) {
        // negative or positive
        return /^[-]?\d+$/.test(val);
    }
```

Comment: `1.1` will fail, is that intentional?

Comment: ...can you break Joren's answser?

Comment: I think his solution is ok

Answer (score -4):

I like this solution:

```
function isNumber(val) {
    return (val >=0 || val < 0);
}
```

Comment: detects true an false.

Comment: Well since true and false can be seen as 1 or 0 I guess that it is a desired functionality.

Comment: "can be seen as" and "is" are two very different things. What happens  when your function returns `true` for a boolean, and so you try to invoke a `Number.prototype` method on the `val`? Oops!